# Fazer Angular4 aguardar o retorno da chamada para API sem timeout

Tags: javascript, api, angular, promises

Preciso realizar uma chamada na API, mas são muitos dados e quero que o Angular aguarde o término. Nesse momento, coloco uma promise, mas ela não aguarda e, enquanto a API está tratando os dados do lado do NodeJS, o Angular realiza uma segunda chamada na API, atropelando e criando duas chamadas na linha de execução. Segue o código da minha service:

```
buscarConsumo(dadosConsumo): Promise<any> {
return this.http.post(`${API_AZURE}/buscarconsumoperiodo`, dadosConsumo)
  .toPromise()
  .then((data) => data)
  .catch((e) => console.log('Erro na Service', e));
}
```

Minha API leva 3 a 4 minutos para terminar, vou tratar isso em banco futuramente, mas no momento preciso trazer os dados para o lado do cliente, tentei colocar timeout mas sem sucesso.

Comment: Se você quer que uma chamada assíncrona só ocorra depois da outra acabar, então é só colocar a segunda dentro do `then` da primeira

Comment: Blza Guilherme, então essa segunda chamada me parece algo automático do angular, eu chamo a API e ela fica rodando, depois de um tempo o angular como não obteve resposta ele manda novamente, eu quero uma forma de não fazer essa segunda chamada ou aumentar meu timeout

Comment: Tenta retorna a promise ou o observable e fazer a logica do then no seu componente.

Comment: Blza @EduardoVargas? Fiz isso e deu certo

Answer (score 0):

Com o conselho do Eduardo deu certo, colocando `then` no componente ele aguarda o termino da requisição no servidor até o final:

```
buscarConsumoTotalResourceGroup(f) {
    this.loading = true;
    this.consumoService.buscarConsumoTotalResourceGroup(this.consumo)
    .toPromise()
    .then((consumoResourceG: any) => {
      this.consumoResourceG = consumoResourceG;
      this.loading = false;
      console.log('Retorno de Consumo Total por ResourceGroup: ', consumoResourceG);
    });
}
```